# How do I resize an image based on window size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I am designing a  and I want the images to shrink on smaller (mobile screens) but enlarge to their max width on a desktop.  A sample page is [located here](http://elitesports-usa.com/index1.php).  In my style sheet ([see here](http://elitesports-usa.com/css/style.css)) I have img set to max-width:100%, but it does not seem to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS is not a HTML language, and it is very sensitive to "gibberish" code. Depending on the browser and their versions, corrupted CSS may be manifested in different ways.**

Please, remove these "separation" lines from your CSS file:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
```

They are corrupting CSS and definitely causing wrong rendering of the style on your page(s).

If you wish or must use them as a visual helper, you must wrap them in a proper CSS comment syntax, like this:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------- */
```

Also, you must remove these characters from line #109:

```
-->
```

---

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

**works fine when added in your CSS**

You should, however, limit your CSS rules to be more specific, above rule will be applied to ALL images on your HTML page, which most of the time is not a desirable effect really (unless it is, of course).

In your particular page, .row seems to be a solid candidate (since you do not have left or right containers). Anyway, to apply it to all rows:

```
.row img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

proof:
[image: css max-width works!]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am new but I am learning!!

Comment: You're welcome :)